# C# replacing a special character in a string

Tags: c#, string, replace, char, newline

This used to be easy in VB but I'm completely stumped in c# VS2010.

I am receiving data form a serial port.  At the end of each line there is a special character which indicates EndOfText.  If you look at it in the terminal window it looks like a little L-shaped bracket. That character is the ASCII "03"

I need to replace that character with  a crlf  ("\r\n").

I have tried the following and it's throwing "Invalid Argument" errors:

```
 RxString = RxString.Replace((char) 03, "\r\n");
```

I can trim the end character and then perform and append of the CRLF  "\r\n" but would rather do it properly in one pass.

Answer (score 6):

There's no overload of `string.Replace` taking a `char` then a `string`. This should work though:

```
RxString = RxString.Replace("\u0003", "\r\n");
```

Comment: There is an overload that accepts char.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts.aspx

Comment: @dknaack : [String.Replace Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)

Comment: @dknaack: the overload accepts a char for both parameters. The string to replace with has to be a string, i.e. \r\n, not a char.

Comment: @sll Yes i know that there is an overload that accepts string too. But i just want to tell that "There's no overload in string.Replace taking a char" is not right.

Comment: @dknaack : So you've to comment the question not this particular answer

Comment: @sll why ? ;) The sentence "There's no overload in string.Replace taking a char then a string" is part of jons answer, not the question.

Comment: @dknaack: Read my answer carefully: there's no overload taking a `char` **then a `string`**.

Comment: Your all right ;) I am too tired, i go to bed now. Thanks anyway!